# How to compile Linux kernel module: printk missing?

Tags: kernel, application-development, gcc, c

So I'm trying to compile a simple kernel module on Ubuntu 18.04, kernel 4-15.32 generic:

```
#define MODULE
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void){ 
    printk("<1> Hello,World\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void){
    printk("<1> Goodbye.\n");
}
```

Notice that I do have `<linux/kernel.h>` , since there are references on forums that this is a frequent omission when error that I have occurs, but in this case I don't have that problem. Compiling this with `gcc -o hello.o hello.c` results in  the `implicit declaration of function 'printk'` error.

So the question is how exactly do I get this most basic kernel module to even compile ?

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved with a couple learned lessons:

- "You must use the kernel headers of the kernel you're compiling against.Using the default `/usr/include/linux` won't
  work" ([source](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/lkmpg.pdf))
- Compiling with `gcc` directly isn't recommended - Kernel has [kbuild system](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt): "The author of an external module should supply a makefile that hides most of the complexity, so one only has to type "make" to build the module."
- `$(PWM)` for some reason doesn't work, but `$(shell pwm)` works. (found [here](http://anshulk.github.io/2014/02/08/syscall_32.h.html)). This also played a role because `M=$(PWM)` would give

  ```
    make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'.  Stop.
  ```

error. Also, per [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) one could also do

```
<pre><code>
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD 
</code></pre>

but haven't tried that.
```

---

Makefile I've used:

```
obj-m += hello.o

KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

The resulting module works as expected and can be inserted and removed with nice messages "<1> Hello World" and "<1> Goodbye" printed to `dmesg`.